# node-gyp configure to release mode

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

Hi I am trying to compile a [node_modules](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) as Release mode, but I could not successfully configure as Release mode.

I ran `node-gyp configure`; the configure.gypi generated

```
 # Do not edit. File was generated by node-gyp's "configure" step {
   "target_defaults": {
         "cflags": [],
         **"default_configuration": "Debug",**
         "defines": [],
         "include_dirs": [],
         "libraries": []   },
```

I tried with `-DBUILDTYPE=Release` and `BUILDTYPE=Release` but not successfully

Answer (score 3):

Default should be `Release`.

Try `node-gyp configure --release`

Comment: This works, thanks! It's not always Release, could be Debug so you'd have to specify --release. I think Debug is when you build node from source with debug on.